# Using a Custom Attribute to assign a formatted value to a property C#

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, formatting, attributes

I want to build a custom attribute to format a variable in a model.

I have a model:

```
public class invoiceModel
{
      public int id { get; set; }
      public DateTime dateDue { get; set; }
      public string dateDueFormatted { get; set; }
      public decimal amountDue { get; set; }
      public string amountDueFormatted { get; set; }
}
```

Right now, I have a service that will format the various strings based on a user setting I have to pull from a table. When I pull in the model or list of models, I then have to loop through and apply the formatting. Not that drastic of a performance hit, but definitely tedious to write over and over again.

The idea is to slap an attribute on the desired variable that I can pass the source variable, culture code, and formatting style I want to use IE:

```
public class invoiceModel
{
      public int id { get; set; }
      //public string cultureCode { get; set; } = "en-us" //Potentially to allow the cultureCode to be dynamically set.
      public DateTime dateDue { get; set; }
      [FormatValue(dateDue, DateTimeFormatTypes.d, "en-us")]
      public string dateDueFormatted { get; set; }
      public decimal amountDue { get; set; }
      [FormatValue(amountDue, CurrencyFormatTypes.C, "en-us")]
      public string amountDueFormatted { get; set; }
}
```

I've seen similar methods dealing with APIKeys that create a custom attribute that pull the value in from the header then get the proper service to validate using IAsyncActionFilter. Here's the attribute I'm currently playing with:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class FormatAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly FormatTypes _formatType;

    private readonly DateTime _dateTimeValue;
    private readonly decimal _decimalValue;
    private readonly DateTimeFormatTypes _dateTimeFormatStyle;
    private readonly CurrencyFormatTypes _currencyFormatStyle;
    private readonly string _cultureCode;

    public FormatAttribute(
        DateTime dateTimeValue,
        DateTimeFormatTypes formatDateTimeStyle,
        string cultureCode)
    {
        _formatType = FormatTypes.DateTime;

        _dateTimeValue = dateTimeValue;
        _dateTimeFormatStyle = formatDateTimeStyle;
        _cultureCode = cultureCode;
    }

    public FormatAttribute(
        decimal decimalValue,
        CurrencyFormatTypes currencyFormatStyle,
        string cultureCode
        )
    {
        _formatType = FormatTypes.Currency;

        _decimalValue = decimalValue;
        _currencyFormatStyle = currencyFormatStyle;
        _cultureCode = cultureCode;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var formatService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IFormatService>();
        switch (_formatType)
        {
            case FormatTypes.DateTime:
                try
                {
                    //TODO: Assign => formatService.FormatDate(_dateTimeValue, _cultureCode, _dateTimeFormatStyle);
                }
                catch { //If any error occurs, just assign null value }
            case FormatTypes.Currency:
                try
                {
                    //TODO: Assign => formatService.FormatCurrency(_decimalValue, _cultureCode, _currencyFormatStyle);
                }
                catch { //If any error occurs, just assign null value }
            default: //If any error occurs, just assign null value
        }
    }
}
```

I know the those aren't proper returns, that's just where I'm wanting to assign the variable. From what I've read, some people are doing some formatting by overriding the validateAttribute, but others are saying that attributes shouldn't be used like this.

Is there a way to make this work or should I look at a different path?

Comment: For me it sounds more like a model mapper problem. You get some data from somewhere as a certain model and then you want to forward a certain model formatted in a certain way to a recipient. Fo rme thats a model mapping problem.

Comment: I did go to lunch and had some time to think on it. Came to the conclusion I was overthinking it. What I probably should be doing is just using the service to get the cultureCode per user settings which is the only call back to the db. After that, I can make the formatting simply an extension and not worry about it.